# Live HTML & PHP editor/IDE for PC?

Tags: php, html, ide

Are there any IDEs on PC which will allow you to view your changes live as you are typing? / Can any IDEs you know of be set up to do that?

For both HTML and PHP ideally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stick a meta refresh in your head, but that will get ugly if you have a lot of php parse errors. You could put the page you want to test inside a frame and have some javascript refresh that frame every few seconds too. Then you could use any IDE and browser you want!

Comment: actually, that's a good idea. parse errors probably won't come in because I have to press Ctrl+S to update the page.

Answer (score 0):

Zend will do this. But be forewarned that seeing a bunch of unfinished PHP code is very ugly. I'd suggest sticking with refreshing your browser.

Oh, and if you actually do anything with that PHP code, like request an RSS feed, you would be making hundreds of calls if it ran the PHP code often.

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) has a debugging tool (plus other cool stuff like type hints, auto-complete and etc.) and allow you to preview your code in a browser. Install xampp, host your php files on your localhost, and you should get almost what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [netbeans](http://netbeans.com) .its free. it is available for all platforms, and mostly it is good for editing php, jsp, java, css, html, ...
Good for SVN, mercurial, Plus you can integrate it easyly with [kenai.com](http://kenai.com)...

it helps with the IntelliSense kind of pop up.

believe me, i'm using it for php development and its the best suited ide i can find...

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse with PHPEclipse** does have live error and syntax highlighting.